# vb.net fails reading xml document

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to read the xml document at this location.

http://portal.panthergroup.co.uk/client_api/get_order/?key=JsKsC25efV&order=2894103&json=0

I display's no problem in my browser but in my project I get the error message

The 'html' start tag on line 3 does not match the end tag of 'head'. Line 5, position 3.  I cannot see anything wrong with the structure of the file.

This was working when last used about 6 months ago, it happens on

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
Dim myString As String = "http://portal.panthergroup.co.uk/client_api/get_order/?key=JsKsC25efV&order=" & row(1) & "&json=0"
doc.Load(myString)
```

I am a little puzzled thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML behind the URL is just fine, and using your code to retrieve it works also.

But the error message

> The 'html' start tag on line 3 does not match the end tag of 'head'. Line 5, position 3.

indicates that the URL you used does not return a XML document, but a HTML page; probably displaying an error message. Check the value of `row(1)` to make sure it contains the right parameter.

Also make sure that the URL is reachable from the machine and the user account your application runs on and there's no security policy/proxy redirecting your request to some kind of login page or something like that.

Comment: I have copied the url and viewed it ok in 2 browsers on serperate machines.  The script was running on SSIS platform, but have copied it onto my development machine and created a little project in .net still the same problem are / allowed as date separators ie 14/09/2014??  thanks

Comment: When you get the above error try `New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(myString)` and check the resulting XML. Maybe that gives you a hint.

Comment: What's up with date separators?

Comment: I just thought it may not like the / I have copied the file local and it runs no problem.

Comment: Thanks your onto something string isn't XML looks like something from our firewall.